# Weyr form of a matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

I have a real Jordan form 
$$ C = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 &  1& 0 & 0\\ 
 -1&  3& 0 &  1& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  3& 1 &0 \\ 
0 &  0&  -1&  3& 0\\ 
0 &  0&  0& 0 & 4
\end{bmatrix} $$

Could you please tell me how to find the Weyr form of $C$?

I confuse because this is not a normal form of Jordan block.

Comment: Do you mean find a similarity transformation to the Weyr form, or the actual matrix in Weyr form, or both?

Answer (score 1):

Because there is only one Jordan block for each eigenvalue (i.e. each eigenvalue has geometric multiplicity $1$), the Weyr and complex Jordan canonical forms coincide.  In particular, the complex Jordan canonical form of your matrix will be
$$
J = \pmatrix{
3+i&1\\
&3+i\\
&&3-i&1\\
&&&3-i\\
&&&&4}
$$
Note that this matrix is already in Weyr canonical form.